# TypeScript omit required parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm exploring TypeScript and I have encountered this declaration function

`export function reduce<V, A = V>(accumulator: (acc: A | V, value: V, index: number) => A): OperatorFunction<V, V | A>;`

It appears that the accumulator function takes three parameters `acc`, `value` and `index`.

None of them is marked with a `?`, indicating that all three are required.

In my specific use case I don't require the `index` parameter, so I omitted it from the `accumulator` function. Surprisingly, this modification still worked without any errors.

I'm curious about how a parameter, which is not marked as a `?`, can still be omitted without causing a TypeScript error. Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: See [the TS FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) and [the Handbook doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions)

Comment: You're allowed to ignore parameters, so why should TS care if you do so explicitly by not naming them?

Comment: @CollinD I expected something like `accumulator: (acc: A | V, value: V, index?: number` if the `index` parameter in the callback function isn't mandatory. Why wouldn't this be the case in a normal function?

Comment: The index parameter isn't optional. Optional means you're allowed to call a function of that type without that argument or with it as `undefined`. You're not calling the function, you're just making a new function of a type that extends that type (and thus you're allowed to pass it, even though it's not exactly the same type. Like how you can pass "foo" for a `string` param, even though the type `"foo"` isn't the same type as `string`), and your function may choose to ignore that param so it doesn't introduce any type-incorrectness to let that cast happen.

Comment: Thanks! It makes a lot of sense now.